# Netlify-lambda serve redirects from netlify.toml

Tags: javascript, redirect, netlify, toml, netlify-function

I have a working netlify-lambda setup. I run netlify-lambda locally and not in the cloud. Upon running

```
netlify-lambda serve ./functions
```

the functions I have defined in the /functions folder are served on localhost:9000

I also have my netlify.toml file in my project root, looking like this:

```
[build]
  functions = "netlify-lambda"
  publish = "build/"
  command = "npm run build"

[[redirects]]
  from = "/test"
  to = "https://google.com"
  status = 200
  force = true
```

When I remove the [build] part, then the command "netlify-lambda serve" will result in an error. So I conclude that this file is being used. On the other hand the [[redirects]] instruction does nothing at all.

Requests to

> localhost:9000/test

or

> localhost:9000/.netlify/functions/test

result in an error like

> Function invocation failed: Error: Cannot find module '/home/********/netlify-lambda/test'

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described here: https://answers.netlify.com/t/redirects-not-going-to-index-html/20289

> Netlify-lambda will only host your functions and nothing else. You’ll need at least the netlify-cli